# Difficulty in creating custom shape with vector drawable

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, vector-graphics

Hi i am developing an app where i'm creating custom shape using vector drawable but somehow my shape doesnt look as expected as you can see in the images below.Please i'm ot so well versed with vector drawables so i would appreciate any help thank you

Here is my current result
[image: current result]

and here is my expected result
[image: expected result]

my vector drawable xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="248dp"
    android:height="148dp"
    android:viewportHeight="12"
    android:viewportWidth="12">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 0,8 C 1,12 5,12 8,12 C 10,12 12,11 15,1 L 12,0 0,0"
        android:strokeWidth="0.1"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: try `M 0,3 0,12 12,12 12,3 C 12,3 10,0 6,0 2,0 0,3 0,3 z` - why dont you use for example inkscape for  drawing your vector shape?

Comment: wow @pskink thanks and to be honest i'm not so well aware with the tools like linkscape but surely now i'll give it a try

Comment: wow @pskink thanks and to be honest i'm not so well aware with the tools like linkscape but surely now i'll give it a try

Comment: https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.92.3/

Comment: just one more thing is that it doesnt take the imageviews match parent

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

**curve.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="248dp"
    android:height="148dp"
    android:viewportHeight="12"
    android:viewportWidth="12">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#2B3147"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 0,12 Q6,5 12,12 L 12,0 0,0"
        android:strokeWidth="0.1" />
</vector>
```

**login.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/curve"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Or Login"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Happy Coding..